# How to update users list using DWR

Tags: java, servlets, dwr

I am developing chat client which can connect to Gtalk and Facebook.I am using DWR for the purpose.

Once I log into I have to populate the user s lists. On client side I have

```
function showUsersOnline() {
    var cellFuncs = [ function(user) {

        return '<i>'+user+'</i>';
    } ];
    LoginG.usersOnline( {
        callback : function(users) {
            dwr.util.removeAllRows('usersOnline');
            dwr.util.addRows("usersOnline", users, cellFuncs, {
                escapeHtml : false
            });
```

On server side I am using Smack Api to get the roster list(online)

```
public void usersOnline() {
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    System.out.println(roster.getEntryCount());
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
        String user = r.getUser();
        Presence presence = roster.getPresence(user);
        if (presence.getType() == Presence.Type.available) {
            System.out.println(user + " is online");
            count1++;

        } else {
            System.out.println(user + " is offline");
            count2++;
        }
```

Now should I return the data as JSON or is there a way DWR can handle the collection???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your server method `usersOnline()` to return the `Collection<RosterEntry>` object then DWR will populate that in the argument of the callback function which in your case is `function(users)`. So after the call is returned back to the callback function `function(users)` you can go through the `users` object to get the updates made to it by the server side method. The `users` object will need to be traversed like an `array` since you are returning a `Collection` or a `List` whatever applies.

Is this what you are looking for? More on this can be read [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/scripting-dwr.html).

Comment: oh so I need not use JSON for servlet to return data... I need to return the collection and tranverse it on the client side... K ll try it out and let u know..Thanks:)

Comment: Precisely. If you have access to a java script debugger then you can set a break point in the callback function and check out the returned object.

Comment: @CoolBeans....... 
At server side I am returning LIST entries which has users 

public List<RosterEntry> usersOnline() {
 
 Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
  List<RosterEntry> entries= (List<RosterEntry>) roster.getEntries();
  return entries;
  }                   
At client I have the same code as above...
When I run the App it s telling Error: undefined, Error
Server side script session id timed out. New session automatically created.... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @xoxoxo - did you set up the dwr.xml properly? You need to add RosterEntry as one of the converter beans. `<convert converter="bean" match="packagename.RosterEntry" />`

Comment: Read more on this URL - http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/converters/bean.html and http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/index.html

Comment: @CoolBeans.... In http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/index.html,the author tells that by default all primitive types,arrays etc are converted  without any declaration.... I tried adding the converter but still gives me the same error

Comment: Were you able to see any more details in the log file? How about the session timeout values? Is it set pretty high in your web.xml?

Comment: Yes - primitives are convetred but List is not a primitive hence you have to add it as a bean to be converted. You will also need to add the method name `usersOnline()` in the dwr.xml.

Comment: @CoolBeans...the default time is 30 min...But once the LoginG.userOnline is called it times out..The response on calling the userOnline is-throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
dwr.engine.remote.handleException("2","0",{javaClassName:"java.lang.Throwable",message:"Error"});

Comment: Do you have all the dwr java scripts included in your jsp page?

Comment: Those would be - `/dwr/interface/dwrAccess.js`, `/dwr/engine.js`, and `/dwr/util.js`

Comment: @CoolBeans...You might want to take a look at the tutorial I am following...http://www.packtpub.com/article/chatroom-application-using-dwr-java-framework... Still the same error

Comment: Your `index.jsp` looks exactly like the one in the tutorial?

Comment: yes the javascipt functions are the same wih additional parameter..LoginG.login(userName,password,loginresult) I am able to login successfully to gtalk and facebook though

Comment: @CoolBeans...Do you have an idea as to where I am going wrong??

Comment: I am not sure why you are seeing the errors. Can you add this in your init-param section of web.xml for the `dwr-invoker` servlet? `<init-param>
    <param-name>allowScriptTagRemoting</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value> </init-param>`

Comment: @CoolBeans...No change at all!!! Am stuck with the same error..I am not getting any error in the log...:(

Comment: That's strange. You get the same `throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';` with it being set to true?

Comment: @CoolBeans- No I dont get 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false' but the response is same                                               //#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
dwr.engine.remote.handleException("2","0",{javaClassName:"java.lang.Throwable",message:"Error"});Server side script session id timed out. New session automatically created
Error: undefined, Error

Comment: Alright. In that case take out the param for allowScriptTagRemoting. It can introduce security vulnerabilities. Are you using DWR 3.0? Looks like reverse ajax polling throws this error which was fixed in 3.0. Check this link - http://bugs.directwebremoting.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-fullcontent/temp/SearchRequest.html?jqlQuery=project+%3D+DWR+AND+component+%3D+engine+ORDER+BY+updated+DESC%2C+priority+DESC%2C+created+ASC&tempMax=1000

Comment: @CoolBeans-Yes I have downloaded the latest version 3.0..Should I post it as a new question?? Thanks Thanks so much for helping me out...

Comment: @xoxoxo - No problem. It is probably a good idea to post the new error as a new question.